# Blender Development

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

I want to ask you some questions about commercial development on Blender.I did not quite understand the license for Blender.
1.If I created some projects on Blender and I start to distribute them I must to pay you some percent of my selling or not?
2.I read on your WebSite that Blender includes some other licenses and after my distributing I must to pay some percent to other companies?

Thanks in advance.
P.S Maybe I ask you some questions in processing our conversation.
And Sorry for incorrect tags I couldn't to find my correct tag.

Sincerely your user Alexander.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because It's about licensing. Please read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/422/are-licensing-questions-off-topic

Answer (score 0):

Blender is licensed under the GNU general public license. http://www.gnu.org/copyleft/gpl.html

(1.) No, as far as I understand it all your earnings are yours and you do not have to pay blender for its use.

(2.) Same answer as number one.